# error trying to implement react-native maps

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to integrate google maps into my react native app I keep getting this error.

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at C:\projects\test\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:205:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\test\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:204:12)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\projects\testnode_modules\metro\src\index.js:58:30)
    at C:\projects\test\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:69:15
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: I'm using the react-native-maps API. https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using **Linux**.

It seems that your process is locked. In a terminal type the following:

`ps -aux | grep '8081`

copy the process ID

type in the terminal

`sudo kill -9 ID-HERE`   replace `ID-HERE` with the process ID.

Restart the application.

If you are using **Windows**

1. type Ctrl+SHIFT+Esc to open the process window
2. Look for your process
3. Right click on the process and choose `end process`
4. Restart the application